# jTableDataSourceModel datalink to iReport gives null

Tags: java, jasper-reports

for report generating I use IReportDesigner.
Put a table to detailbend1 with only 2 cols, fill the col with field parameter
COLUMN_0 and COLUMN_1 defined in the corresponding table dataset "Zeittab" Fields.

[image]

In Java the code should fill the reporttable:

```
DefaultTableModel tazeit = (DefaultTableModel)jTable2.getModel();        
JasperReport jasperReport;
JasperPrint jasperPrint;

HashMap<String, Object> parameter = new HashMap<String, Object>();

parameter.put("maschine", jTextField7.getText());

try {           
    jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("jrxml/reporttest02.jrxml");
    jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameter, new JRTableModelDataSource(jTable2.getModel()));
    JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint, true);
}
catch (JRException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But it reports only null in both tablecols.

The xml part for the table in IReportDesigner:

```
    <detail>
    <band height="30" splitType="Stretch">
        <elementGroup/>
        <componentElement>
            <reportElement x="20" y="0" width="279" height="30" uuid="16877d28-e650-4f23-9087-937a5f072a21">
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.VerticalRowLayout"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.table_header" value="Table_TH"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.column_header" value="Table_CH"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.detail" value="Table_TD"/>
            </reportElement>
            <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                <datasetRun subDataset="Zeittab" uuid="162a78f5-b35f-4eb3-bfc2-73fe9c00adb4">
                    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource()]]></dataSourceExpression>
                </datasetRun>
                <jr:column width="130" uuid="b25fe72b-f6c7-4a18-add1-50e4a9e951a6">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column1"/>
                    <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="130" height="30" uuid="e335c7d7-bbb4-4ea9-adfd-b6bfae26ac9e"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{COLUMN_0}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
                <jr:column width="150" uuid="3fc1a8fc-5245-4980-90c4-a27dbe5f46fa">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column2"/>
                    <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="150" height="30" uuid="1d6321c6-f2b9-43e7-8814-bd13404cfd79"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{COLUMN_1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
            </jr:table>
        </componentElement>
    </band>
</detail>
```

The questions:
Should I make a parameter insert of the "Zeittab" like:

```
JRDataSource ds = new JRTableModelDataSource(jTable2.getModel());
parameter.put("Zeittab", ds);
```

I tried this, but there was also null in the report.

There is no error message in Netbeans that gives an hint.

Maybe the fault is in the empty JREmptyDatasource in XML:

```
<datasetRun subDataset="Zeittab" uuid="162a78f5-b35f-4eb3-bfc2-73fe9c00adb4">
<dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource()]]></dataSourceExpression>
                </datasetRun>
```

How may I solve the datalink between the jTable to the cols in the report?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.
I explain it with a 3 column table, columns named as material, anzahl, info.

First of all the declaration in the jasper xml file, init the parameter name:

```
<parameter name="MaterialCollection" class="java.util.Collection"/>
```

Then the table declaration in the jasper xml file:

```
<jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
<datasetRun subDataset="MaterialDataset" uuid="ac99630e-03c5-41d1-a0a5-a054a4ffc607">
    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{MaterialCollection})]]></dataSourceExpression>
</datasetRun>
<jr:column width="227" uuid="9a486baa-c231-461d-a816-b49e69d0e287">
    <jr:columnHeader style="table 15_CH" height="14" rowSpan="1">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="3" y="0" width="224" height="14" uuid="1fa2f252-3900-47db-9026-277847285dd4"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="7" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Material]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </jr:columnHeader>
    <jr:detailCell style="table 15_TD" height="12" rowSpan="1">
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="3" y="0" width="224" height="12" uuid="1a6bf583-a396-49cb-8c36-72fb19c83440"/>
            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="7"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{material}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </jr:detailCell>
</jr:column>
<jr:column width="36" uuid="dea2ad4c-6756-488e-90e7-053d2d3430be">
    <jr:columnHeader style="table 15_CH" height="14" rowSpan="1">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="0" y="0" width="36" height="14" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="234a9f2c-c163-4c77-af3a-cac70c258153"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" rotation="None" markup="none">
                <font fontName="SansSerif" size="7" isBold="true" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
                <paragraph lineSpacing="Single"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Anzahl]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </jr:columnHeader>
    <jr:detailCell style="table 15_TD" height="12" rowSpan="1">
        <textField pattern="" isBlankWhenNull="false">
            <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="0" y="0" width="36" height="12" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="b7924b73-a0f5-45d7-b175-ece4bdf65799"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" rotation="None" markup="none">
                <font fontName="SansSerif" size="7" isBold="false" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
                <paragraph lineSpacing="Single"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{anzahl}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </jr:detailCell>
</jr:column>
<jr:column width="271" uuid="a098e0f8-8447-413d-8436-cb01dbaebb85">
    <jr:columnHeader style="table 15_CH" height="14" rowSpan="1">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="3" y="0" width="268" height="14" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="9d00320e-69cf-4d06-a099-e7c3c3c91344"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" rotation="None" markup="none">
                <font fontName="SansSerif" size="7" isBold="true" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
                <paragraph lineSpacing="Single"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Info]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </jr:columnHeader>
    <jr:detailCell style="table 15_TD" height="12" rowSpan="1">
        <textField pattern="" isBlankWhenNull="false">
            <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="3" y="0" width="268" height="12" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="c3101aa2-53ff-4ffe-99ca-b29232bfb6fc"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle" rotation="None" markup="none">
                <font fontName="SansSerif" size="7" isBold="false" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
                <paragraph lineSpacing="Single"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{info}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </jr:detailCell>
</jr:column>
```

In the javacode I create a class with the column names from the jasper xml declaration:

```
public class Materialtabelle implements Serializable {
  public  String material;
  public  String anzahl;
  public  String info;

  public String getMaterial(){ return material; }
  public void setMaterial(String material){ this.material = material; }
  public String getAnzahl(){ return anzahl; }
  public void setAnzahl(String anzahl){ this.anzahl = anzahl; }
  public String getInfo(){ return info; }
  public void setInfo(String info){ this.info = info; }
}
```

Then I fill it with my table data, named ma:

```
Materialtabelle matZeile = null;
    Collection matListe=new ArrayList<Materialtabelle>();
    for(int i = 0; i < jTable1.getRowCount(); i++){
        matZeile = new Materialtabelle();
        matZeile.setMaterial(((String)ma.getValueAt(i, 0)) == null ? " " : (String)ma.getValueAt(i, 0));
        matZeile.setAnzahl(((String)ma.getValueAt(i, 1)) == null ? " " : (String)ma.getValueAt(i, 1));
        matZeile.setInfo((String)ma.getValueAt(i, 2) == null ? " " : (String)ma.getValueAt(i, 2));
        matListe.add(matZeile);
   }
```

After this, I put the data over a parameter to the report:

```
HashMap<String, Object> parameter = new HashMap<String, Object>();
parameter.put("MaterialCollection", matListe);
```

Then call the standard for creating the jasperreport, i use a jasperfile, which is a compiled jasper xml template:

```
JasperReport jasperReport;
JasperPrint jasperPrint;

jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(new File(syspfad + "reporttest01.jasper"));     
jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameter, new JREmptyDataSource());
JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint, false);
```